# htaccess,Codeigniter, domain for static content, use index.php when image not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Problem:

1.example.com is using Codeigniter to serve Webpages with Products.

2.Product images are present in the folder

> /static/prods/

Css are present in folder

> /static/css/

And js in folder

> /static/js/

3.All static content images,css,js need to be served using a different sub domain

> images.example.com/prods/productid.png
>
> images.example.com/css/styles.css
>
> images.example.com/js/script.js

4.However if 
   images.example.com/prods/productid.png

does not exist, it should serve Productimage generated by Codeigniter path(no redirect)

> /index.php?/static/prodid.png

where 'static' is a function on the 'home' controller .

5.Apache 2.2

6.What would be the correct htaccess?

Current configuration:

My htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Render static files
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} images.example.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !static/
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} images.example.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !static/
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://images.example.com/static/$1 [L,R=303]

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


   #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
   #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
   #request to index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
 </IfModule>
```

If Product image 'images.example.com/prods/productid.png' does not exist it should redirect to images.example.com/index.php?/static/prods/productid.png

Instead it redirects to https://images.example.com/static/index.php?/static/index.php

Any ideas or inputs you require?

Comment: I am still not able to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any expert help me please? I have not getting any help from anywhere.